# Огонь, вода и медные трубы

Tags: фразеология

Думаю, это выражение знают все. Но из трех испытаний я знаю только "медные трубы" - испытание властью (самое трудное).
А вот как насчет остальных? Речь о каких-то конкретных проверках? Или же это просто фигуральное выражение, подразумевающее какие-то трудности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огонь и вода символизируют жизненные трудности, а медные трубы (слава)- более позднее добавление.

Испытание огнем и водой выдерживают многие герои, а пройти потом через медные трубы этим же героям (совершившим подвиги, за что и досталась им слава) удается далеко не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ОГОНЬ и ВОДА буквально были препятствием для героя какого-нибудь сказания, а потом люди стали так говорить образно на трудности, препятствия по мере их сложности.